# Unable to get distinct results for queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

here is models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):

    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand , related_name='products')
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category', verbose_name='categories', related_name='products' , default='')
        parent = models.ForeignKey('self' , related_name = 'children' , null=True , blank=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class StoreProduct(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product')
        category = models.ForeignKey('products.Category')
        store = models.ForeignKey('Store')

class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , null=True , blank=True)
    StoreName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default = '')
    items = models.ManyToManyField('products.Product', through=StoreProduct)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('products.Brand' , null=True , blank=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default = '')
    Area = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default = '')
    Address = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    MallName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True ,unique=True)
```

here is views.py

```
queryset = StoreProduct.objects.all().distinct()
```

Multiple store can contain the same product and but they should appear once on the product grid page.
Distinct query is not working.
What can i do to show distinct values in the above case?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does "not working" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: What database are you using? If you are on postgres, you could use `distinct('store')`

Comment: i am using sqlite3...i tried with distinct('product__title') ....but it throws error distinct on not applicable with the db

Comment: What database are you going to be using for production?

Comment: i will use my sql for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL, specify the level of distinction:

```
queryset = StoreProduct.objects.distinct('product')
```

you can also use it in conjunction with `values()`, `order_by()`, etc:

```
queryset = StoreProduct.objects.values('product').distinct()
```

I will suggest the following as solution but not the solution; either you choose PosgreSQL as database, specially that the newest Django version is coming with more built-in support for complex data structure, or you try make you own filter as follow (but in case you have large dataset this will be really bad):

```
store_product_id_list = StoreProduct.objects.values('product').distinct()
store_product_list = []
for obj in store_product_id_list:
    store_product_obj = StoreProduct.objects.filter(product_id=obj.get('product')).first()
    store_product_list.append(store_product_obj)
```

Check [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) for more examples

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first'

Comment: [{'product': 1}, {'product': 2}, {'product': 3}]

Comment: I'm happy that this finally works for you. But I will really recommend to consider PostgreSQL in your future project. It will make your life easier and offer you more performance.

Comment: When you have to deal with complex database structure, PostgreSQL is the most recommended, you can work with MySQL but you will find your self sometimes in need to do additional work that requires advanced level or can harm your project performance.

Comment: i am unable to filter the results further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98574/discussion-between-dhiatn-and-adrafe-rinzzler).

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'